# Laravel 4 - Logging inside the event listener

Tags: php, events, logging, laravel, laravel-4

I'm quite new to `laravel 4`, and I want to log to files inside `storage/logs` when a `user` attempt to connect to my application.

I have added inside `routes.php` this:

```php
Event::listen('auth.attempt', function() {
    echo 'attempting to logging in';
});
```

I know that `Laravel 4` includes `monolog` which is a PHP logging framework , but I dont know if it's the easiest way to log here.

I can declare a `filter` that I add to the `before` of my `route`, but this solution isn't very elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go with monolog, it is widely used and a great library. It can be configured in many different ways and implements the PSR-3 logging interface. See http://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging and http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog‎.

Most simple logging command:

```
Log::info('This is some useful information.');
```

If you want to directly interface with monolog:

```
$monolog = Log::getMonolog();
```

By using the standard laravel facade for monolog it will automatically log it into a new file with the current date.

Regarding your initial query about the easiest method, I feel compelled to say this is the easiest one.